# Windows reporting 1Gbps but file transfer speed only 100Mbps

Tags: networking, local-area-network, network-speed

Things I checked:

- Windows adapter status confirms 1 Gbps connection on both PCs
- Removed other PCs connected to the network
- Both PCs are connected to TP-Link Archer A6
- Isolated HDD speed by using iperf
- iperf shows speeds of around 95-99Mbps which leads me to believe it is somehow capped at 100Mbps

Both PCs running updated Windows 10 
Transferring 4GB file through Windows Explorer

Comment: If the PCs are connected via Wi-Fi, then that is about the right transfer rate. Wireless slow things down a lot, especially between machines on the same WAP (the WAP cannot both send and receive at the same time).

Comment: To note, QoS on the NIC would reserve almost 80% of the speed to the OS, thus give you the remaining, please validate QoS is OFF, unthinked

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely the network would be the bottleneck here, but the HDD might be.

> A typical 7200 RPM HDD will deliver a read/write speed of 80-160MB/s.
>   On the other hand, a typical SSD will deliver read/write speed of
>   between 200 MB/s to 550 MB/s. ([TekHattan](https://tekhattan.com/blog/hardware/ssd-vs-hdd-speed-lifespan-and-reliability/))

Windows Explorer could be a culprit, too, but it usually slows file transfers down when copying multiple files. In that case, using a command line tool would help, the coolest one being [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).